# How to create and delay an animation in objective-c?

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation

I have a 5x5 checkers board kind of custom `UIView` which fills the box I click on to black. I want to create an animation where the program remembers my clicks in order and after i push on a button it animates and fills the boxes to black in the order that i did. How can I create this kind of animation with, say, 2 seconds between each transition?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Keep an Array to track your order and do the animation with the DISPATCH_AFTER block.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a NSTimer to wait 2 seconds, and go through an animation array that you defined.

So, first u need to store your clicks order

`NSMutableArray * clicks = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];`

In your ".h" declare a int counter: `int cont`, and set it as 0.

Then, when you whant to start animating, initialize the NSTimer:

`NSTimer * timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:2.0
                        target:self
                        selector:@selector(fillAnotherSquare:)
                        userInfo:nil
                        repeats:YES];`

Finally, yout method "fillAnotherSquare"

```
-(void) fillAnotherSquare: (id ) sender{
      if (cont == squareNumbers)
          [timer invalidate];

       /* Fill the square with index "cont" */
}
```